# How can Gretl data be exported to use in Stata

Tags: stata, gretl

We are in a class on introductory econometrics and need to export data from Gretl so that  Stata users can import it.

Seems that there is a tool to make it (Stat/Transfer), but it's not free.

Has anyone a tested method to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about loading data into a program. I also think it is too simplistic and has not enough of a reproducible example for stack overflow.

Comment: It seems to me that it is more off-topic in stack overflow that in stats.stackexchange.com, there it was about a software of specific use to teach econometric investigation, here it is a question about any software.

the description for that site says "for ... statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization"

Comment: Thanks by the improvements @nick-cox, but I'm not sure if that "free" shouldn't be an "open", seems to me that it would be more accurate.

Comment: See advice on software-related questions at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic I don't think this needs "statistical expertise" to answer; so in my view it was not on-topic in CV. I don't think it is especially on-topic here either.

Comment: @Rafareino If it were free, wouldn't you use it to solve your problem?  Whether it's open source is secondary (for the record, it isn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `gretl.export(vars)` to export to a csv file in gretl's temp directory, which can be read into Stata with `import delimited`.

Answer (score 1):

Gretl will happily write is Stata format. You can either use the graphical user interface for this (File>Export) or the `store` command, as in

```
store mydata.dta
```